# Curvature and torsion of this curve

Tags: differential-geometry

i was trying to  get curvature and torsion of curve in mathematica. of this curve

```
r[t_]:= {t*Sqrt[2]*Sin[Pi*t]*(Sin[Pi/2*t])^2,((1-t)*Sqrt[2]*Sin[Pi*t]*(Sin[Pi/2*t])^2)+(t*Sqrt[2]*Sin[Pi*t]*(Cos[Pi/2*t])^2),(1-t)*Sqrt[2]*Sin[Pi*t]*(Cos[Pi/2*t])^2}

Simplify[FrenetSerretSystem[r[t],t]]
```

i wanted to get it in this way. but it is giving   me strange result. can anyone help me to get it's curvature curve in any kind of way and it's plot?

Comment: I do get a very complicated solution but it is truncated because it is too long, which error do you get?

Comment: Things do simplify a bit if you add assumptions to Simplify. For example, the curvatures: `{c1, c2} = FrenetSerretSystem[r[t], t][[1]]` And then `FullSimplify[c1, Assumptions -> t > 0]`  gives you something that will fit on one screen.

Comment: craig carter , i get this error

Comment: craig carter , i get this error     Assumptions - cannot be followed by > t>0

Comment: can you help me plot the curvature and function. i was simulating a paper and my result was not following the paper.

Comment: Can you check that you didn’t leave out the rule? `Assumptions-> t>0`

Comment: "I was simulating a paper" - can you provide a link to this paper you speak of?

Comment: 1) Since you are only interested in curvature, it is straightforward to use the `ArcCurvature`function. 2) Using `FullSimplify` and limiting the argument makes a bit shorter expression. Try this: `k = FullSimplify[ArcCurvature[r[t], t], 0 < t < 2 \[Pi]]`. Stil it has 490 leaves.

Answer (score 2):

Since the plot of the curve is weird,

```
r[t_]:={t*Sqrt[2]*Sin[Pi*t]*(Sin[Pi/2*t])^2,((1-t)*Sqrt[2]*Sin[Pi*t]*(Sin[Pi/2*t])^2)+(t*Sqrt[2]*Sin[Pi*t]*(Cos[Pi/2*t])^2),(1-t)*Sqrt[2]*Sin[Pi*t]*(Cos[Pi/2*t])^2};
ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

, nothing strange that the result of

```
Simplify[FrenetSerretSystem[r[t], t]]
```

> `{{(2 Sqrt[ 2] \[Pi] \[Sqrt](240 + 591 \[Pi]^2 + 80 \[Pi]^4 -  492 \[Pi]^2 t - 320 \[Pi]^4 t + 492 \[Pi]^2 t^2 +  560 \[Pi]^4 t^2 - 480 \[Pi]^4 t^3 + 240 \[Pi]^4 t^4 +  126 \[Pi]^2 (-1 + 2 t) Cos[\[Pi] t] -  1/2 (720 + \[Pi]^2 (-325 - 972 t + 972 t^2) +  48 \[Pi]^4 (1 - 4 t + 7 t^2 - 6 t^3 + 3 t^4)) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + 120 \[Pi]^2 Cos[3 \[Pi] t] -  240 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[3 \[Pi] t] + 144 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  195 \[Pi]^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 48 \[Pi]^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  108 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] + 192 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  108 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  336 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  288 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  144 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 12 \[Pi]^2 Cos[5 \[Pi] t] +  24 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[5 \[Pi] t] - 24 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  139/2 \[Pi]^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] - 8 \[Pi]^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  102 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 32 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  102 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  56 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  48 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  24 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 18 \[Pi]^2 Cos[7 \[Pi] t] -  36 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[7 \[Pi] t] + 6 \[Pi]^2 Cos[8 \[Pi] t] +  568 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] + 264 \[Pi]^3 Sin[\[Pi] t] -  536 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[\[Pi] t] + 536 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[\[Pi] t] -  180 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 4 \[Pi]^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  360 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 244 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  756 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  504 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - 240 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  96 \[Pi]^3 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] - 144 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  144 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] + 144 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  136 \[Pi]^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] - 288 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  344 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  216 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  144 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 64 \[Pi] Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  32 \[Pi]^3 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 80 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  80 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 36 \[Pi] Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  36 \[Pi]^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] + 72 \[Pi] t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  108 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  108 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  72 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] - 24 \[Pi] Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  8 \[Pi]^3 Sin[7 \[Pi] t] - 24 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  24 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[7 \[Pi] t]))/(7 + 8 \[Pi]^2 -  16 \[Pi]^2 t + 16 \[Pi]^2 t^2 +  4 (-1 + \[Pi]^2 (1 - t + t^2)) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + (-3 + 4 \[Pi]^2 (1 - 3 t + 3 t^2)) Cos[ 4 \[Pi] t] + 6 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] - 4 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  8 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - 2 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] -  6 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 12 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t])^( 3/2), (16 Sqrt[ 2] \[Pi]^2 (9 \[Pi] - 18 \[Pi] t - 34 \[Pi] Cos[\[Pi] t] -  14 \[Pi] (-1 + 2 t) Cos[2 \[Pi] t] +  9 \[Pi] Cos[3 \[Pi] t] + \[Pi] Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  2 \[Pi] t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] + \[Pi] Cos[5 \[Pi] t] -  62 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - 5 Sin[4 \[Pi] t]))/(480 + 1182 \[Pi]^2 +  160 \[Pi]^4 - 984 \[Pi]^2 t - 640 \[Pi]^4 t + 984 \[Pi]^2 t^2 +  1120 \[Pi]^4 t^2 - 960 \[Pi]^4 t^3 + 480 \[Pi]^4 t^4 +  252 \[Pi]^2 (-1 +  2 t) Cos[\[Pi] t] + (-720 + \[Pi]^2 (325 + 972 t - 972 t^2) -  48 \[Pi]^4 (1 - 4 t + 7 t^2 - 6 t^3 + 3 t^4)) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + 240 \[Pi]^2 Cos[3 \[Pi] t] -  480 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[3 \[Pi] t] + 288 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  390 \[Pi]^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 96 \[Pi]^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  216 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] + 384 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  216 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  672 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  576 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  288 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 24 \[Pi]^2 Cos[5 \[Pi] t] +  48 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[5 \[Pi] t] - 48 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  139 \[Pi]^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] - 16 \[Pi]^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  204 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 64 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  204 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  112 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 96 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  48 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 36 \[Pi]^2 Cos[7 \[Pi] t] -  72 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[7 \[Pi] t] + 12 \[Pi]^2 Cos[8 \[Pi] t] +  1136 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] + 528 \[Pi]^3 Sin[\[Pi] t] -  1072 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[\[Pi] t] + 1072 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[\[Pi] t] -  360 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 8 \[Pi]^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  720 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 488 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  1512 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  1008 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - 480 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  192 \[Pi]^3 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] - 288 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  288 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] + 288 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  272 \[Pi]^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] - 576 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  688 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 432 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  288 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 128 \[Pi] Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  64 \[Pi]^3 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 160 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  160 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 72 \[Pi] Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  72 \[Pi]^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] + 144 \[Pi] t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  216 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] + 216 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  144 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] - 48 \[Pi] Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  16 \[Pi]^3 Sin[7 \[Pi] t] - 48 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  48 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[7 \[Pi] t])}, {{(4 Sin[(\[Pi] t)/ 2]^2 (\[Pi] t + 2 \[Pi] t Cos[\[Pi] t] +  Sin[\[Pi] t]))/(\[Sqrt](7 + 8 \[Pi]^2 - 16 \[Pi]^2 t +  16 \[Pi]^2 t^2 +  4 (-1 + \[Pi]^2 (1 - t + t^2)) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + (-3 + 4 \[Pi]^2 (1 - 3 t + 3 t^2)) Cos[ 4 \[Pi] t] + 6 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] -  4 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 8 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  2 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] - 6 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  12 \[Pi] t Sin[ 4 \[Pi] t])), (2 (\[Pi] Cos[\[Pi] t] + \[Pi] (-1 + 2 t) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + Sin[2 \[Pi] t]))/(\[Sqrt](7 + 8 \[Pi]^2 -  16 \[Pi]^2 t + 16 \[Pi]^2 t^2 +  4 (-1 + \[Pi]^2 (1 - t + t^2)) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + (-3 + 4 \[Pi]^2 (1 - 3 t + 3 t^2)) Cos[ 4 \[Pi] t] + 6 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] -  4 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 8 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  2 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] - 6 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  12 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t])), -((4 Cos[(\[Pi] t)/ 2]^2 (\[Pi] - \[Pi] t + 2 \[Pi] (-1 + t) Cos[\[Pi] t] +  Sin[\[Pi] t]))/(\[Sqrt](7 + 8 \[Pi]^2 - 16 \[Pi]^2 t +  16 \[Pi]^2 t^2 +  4 (-1 + \[Pi]^2 (1 - t + t^2)) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + (-3 + 4 \[Pi]^2 (1 - 3 t + 3 t^2)) Cos[ 4 \[Pi] t] + 6 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] -  4 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 8 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  2 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] - 6 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  12 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t])))}, {(Sin[(\[Pi] t)/ 2] (2 \[Pi] (9 + 4 (1 + 7 \[Pi]^2) t - 44 \[Pi]^2 t^2 +  44 \[Pi]^2 t^3) Cos[(\[Pi] t)/2] +  4 \[Pi] (-6 + 17 t + 18 \[Pi]^2 t - 34 \[Pi]^2 t^2 +  34 \[Pi]^2 t^3) Cos[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] -  54 \[Pi] Cos[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] + 28 \[Pi] t Cos[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] +  40 \[Pi]^3 t Cos[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] -  104 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Cos[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] +  104 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Cos[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] +  31 \[Pi] Cos[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] - 62 \[Pi] t Cos[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] +  16 \[Pi]^3 t Cos[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] -  32 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Cos[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] +  32 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Cos[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] +  23 \[Pi] Cos[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] - 42 \[Pi] t Cos[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] +  8 \[Pi]^3 t Cos[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] -  24 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Cos[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] +  24 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Cos[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] +  6 \[Pi] Cos[(11 \[Pi] t)/2] + 24 Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] -  20 \[Pi]^2 Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] - 26 \[Pi]^2 t Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] +  36 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] + 48 Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] +  68 \[Pi]^2 Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] -  110 \[Pi]^2 t Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] +  84 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] + 16 Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] -  20 \[Pi]^2 Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] +  14 \[Pi]^2 t Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] +  68 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] - 20 Sin[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] +  20 \[Pi]^2 Sin[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] -  56 \[Pi]^2 t Sin[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] +  68 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Sin[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] - 12 Sin[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] +  8 \[Pi]^2 Sin[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] -  38 \[Pi]^2 t Sin[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] +  48 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Sin[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] +  8 \[Pi]^2 Sin[(11 \[Pi] t)/2] -  12 \[Pi]^2 t Sin[(11 \[Pi] t)/2]))/(\[Sqrt](7/2 + 4 \[Pi]^2 -  8 \[Pi]^2 t + 8 \[Pi]^2 t^2 +  2 (-1 + \[Pi]^2 (1 - t + t^2)) Cos[2 \[Pi] t] +  1/2 (-3 + 4 \[Pi]^2 (1 - 3 t + 3 t^2)) Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  3 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] - 2 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  4 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] -  3 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  6 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t]) \[Sqrt](480 + 1182 \[Pi]^2 +  160 \[Pi]^4 - 984 \[Pi]^2 t - 640 \[Pi]^4 t +  984 \[Pi]^2 t^2 + 1120 \[Pi]^4 t^2 - 960 \[Pi]^4 t^3 +  480 \[Pi]^4 t^4 +  252 \[Pi]^2 (-1 +  2 t) Cos[\[Pi] t] + (-720 + \[Pi]^2 (325 + 972 t -  972 t^2) -  48 \[Pi]^4 (1 - 4 t + 7 t^2 - 6 t^3 + 3 t^4)) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + 240 \[Pi]^2 Cos[3 \[Pi] t] -  480 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[3 \[Pi] t] + 288 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  390 \[Pi]^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 96 \[Pi]^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  216 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  384 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  216 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  672 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  576 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  288 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 24 \[Pi]^2 Cos[5 \[Pi] t] +  48 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[5 \[Pi] t] - 48 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  139 \[Pi]^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] - 16 \[Pi]^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  204 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 64 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  204 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  112 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  96 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  48 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 36 \[Pi]^2 Cos[7 \[Pi] t] -  72 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[7 \[Pi] t] + 12 \[Pi]^2 Cos[8 \[Pi] t] +  1136 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] + 528 \[Pi]^3 Sin[\[Pi] t] -  1072 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[\[Pi] t] +  1072 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[\[Pi] t] - 360 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  8 \[Pi]^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 720 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  488 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  1512 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  1008 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - 480 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  192 \[Pi]^3 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] - 288 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  288 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] + 288 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  272 \[Pi]^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] - 576 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  688 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  432 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  288 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 128 \[Pi] Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  64 \[Pi]^3 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 160 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  160 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 72 \[Pi] Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  72 \[Pi]^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] + 144 \[Pi] t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  216 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  216 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  144 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] - 48 \[Pi] Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  16 \[Pi]^3 Sin[7 \[Pi] t] - 48 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  48 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[7 \[Pi] t])), (-24 - 3 \[Pi]^2 +  36 \[Pi]^2 t - 36 \[Pi]^2 t^2 -  34 \[Pi]^2 (-1 + 2 t) Cos[\[Pi] t] +  2 (16 + \[Pi]^2 (25 - 8 t + 8 t^2)) Cos[2 \[Pi] t] +  17 \[Pi]^2 Cos[3 \[Pi] t] - 34 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[3 \[Pi] t] -  8 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] + 15 \[Pi]^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  20 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] + 20 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  13 \[Pi]^2 Cos[5 \[Pi] t] - 26 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[5 \[Pi] t] +  2 \[Pi]^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] - 64 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] -  8 \[Pi]^3 Sin[\[Pi] t] + 24 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[\[Pi] t] -  24 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[\[Pi] t] + 20 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  16 \[Pi]^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - 40 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  48 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 48 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  32 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 2 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  12 \[Pi]^3 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] - 36 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  36 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] - 10 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  4 \[Pi]^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 20 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  12 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 12 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  8 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] - 14 \[Pi] Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  4 \[Pi]^3 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 12 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  12 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[ 5 \[Pi] t])/(\[Sqrt](7/2 + 4 \[Pi]^2 - 8 \[Pi]^2 t +  8 \[Pi]^2 t^2 +  2 (-1 + \[Pi]^2 (1 - t + t^2)) Cos[2 \[Pi] t] +  1/2 (-3 + 4 \[Pi]^2 (1 - 3 t + 3 t^2)) Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  3 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] - 2 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  4 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] -  3 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  6 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t]) \[Sqrt](480 + 1182 \[Pi]^2 +  160 \[Pi]^4 - 984 \[Pi]^2 t - 640 \[Pi]^4 t +  984 \[Pi]^2 t^2 + 1120 \[Pi]^4 t^2 - 960 \[Pi]^4 t^3 +  480 \[Pi]^4 t^4 +  252 \[Pi]^2 (-1 +  2 t) Cos[\[Pi] t] + (-720 + \[Pi]^2 (325 + 972 t -  972 t^2) -  48 \[Pi]^4 (1 - 4 t + 7 t^2 - 6 t^3 + 3 t^4)) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + 240 \[Pi]^2 Cos[3 \[Pi] t] -  480 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[3 \[Pi] t] + 288 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  390 \[Pi]^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 96 \[Pi]^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  216 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  384 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  216 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  672 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  576 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  288 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 24 \[Pi]^2 Cos[5 \[Pi] t] +  48 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[5 \[Pi] t] - 48 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  139 \[Pi]^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] - 16 \[Pi]^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  204 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 64 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  204 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  112 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  96 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  48 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 36 \[Pi]^2 Cos[7 \[Pi] t] -  72 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[7 \[Pi] t] + 12 \[Pi]^2 Cos[8 \[Pi] t] +  1136 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] + 528 \[Pi]^3 Sin[\[Pi] t] -  1072 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[\[Pi] t] +  1072 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[\[Pi] t] - 360 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  8 \[Pi]^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 720 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  488 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  1512 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  1008 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - 480 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  192 \[Pi]^3 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] - 288 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  288 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] + 288 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  272 \[Pi]^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] - 576 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  688 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  432 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  288 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 128 \[Pi] Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  64 \[Pi]^3 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 160 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  160 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 72 \[Pi] Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  72 \[Pi]^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] + 144 \[Pi] t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  216 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  216 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  144 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] - 48 \[Pi] Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  16 \[Pi]^3 Sin[7 \[Pi] t] - 48 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  48 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[7 \[Pi] t])), -((Cos[(\[Pi] t)/ 2] ((-24 + \[Pi]^2 (10 + 46 t - 36 t^2)) Cos[(\[Pi] t)/ 2] + (48 + \[Pi]^2 (42 - 58 t + 84 t^2)) Cos[(3 \[Pi] t)/ 2] - 16 Cos[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] -  62 \[Pi]^2 Cos[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] +  150 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] -  68 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] - 20 Cos[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] +  32 \[Pi]^2 Cos[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] -  80 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] +  68 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] + 12 Cos[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] -  18 \[Pi]^2 Cos[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] +  58 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] -  48 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] -  4 \[Pi]^2 Cos[(11 \[Pi] t)/2] +  12 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[(11 \[Pi] t)/2] -  26 \[Pi] Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] - 56 \[Pi]^3 Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] +  8 \[Pi] t Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] +  144 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] -  176 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] +  88 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] +  44 \[Pi] Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] +  72 \[Pi]^3 Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] -  68 \[Pi] t Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] -  208 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] +  272 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] -  136 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] +  26 \[Pi] Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] -  40 \[Pi]^3 Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] +  28 \[Pi] t Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] +  144 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] -  208 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] +  104 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] -  31 \[Pi] Sin[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] +  16 \[Pi]^3 Sin[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] +  62 \[Pi] t Sin[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] -  48 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] +  64 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] -  32 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] +  19 \[Pi] Sin[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] -  8 \[Pi]^3 Sin[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] -  42 \[Pi] t Sin[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] +  32 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] -  48 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] +  24 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[(9 \[Pi] t)/2] +  6 \[Pi] Sin[(11 \[Pi] t)/2]))/(\[Sqrt](7/2 + 4 \[Pi]^2 -  8 \[Pi]^2 t + 8 \[Pi]^2 t^2 +  2 (-1 + \[Pi]^2 (1 - t + t^2)) Cos[2 \[Pi] t] +  1/2 (-3 + 4 \[Pi]^2 (1 - 3 t + 3 t^2)) Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  3 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] - 2 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  4 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] -  3 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  6 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t]) \[Sqrt](480 + 1182 \[Pi]^2 +  160 \[Pi]^4 - 984 \[Pi]^2 t - 640 \[Pi]^4 t +  984 \[Pi]^2 t^2 + 1120 \[Pi]^4 t^2 - 960 \[Pi]^4 t^3 +  480 \[Pi]^4 t^4 +  252 \[Pi]^2 (-1 +  2 t) Cos[\[Pi] t] + (-720 + \[Pi]^2 (325 + 972 t -  972 t^2) -  48 \[Pi]^4 (1 - 4 t + 7 t^2 - 6 t^3 + 3 t^4)) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + 240 \[Pi]^2 Cos[3 \[Pi] t] -  480 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[3 \[Pi] t] + 288 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  390 \[Pi]^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 96 \[Pi]^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  216 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  384 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  216 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  672 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  576 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  288 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  24 \[Pi]^2 Cos[5 \[Pi] t] + 48 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[5 \[Pi] t] -  48 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 139 \[Pi]^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  16 \[Pi]^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] - 204 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  64 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  204 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  112 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  96 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  48 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  36 \[Pi]^2 Cos[7 \[Pi] t] - 72 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[7 \[Pi] t] +  12 \[Pi]^2 Cos[8 \[Pi] t] + 1136 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] +  528 \[Pi]^3 Sin[\[Pi] t] - 1072 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[\[Pi] t] +  1072 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[\[Pi] t] - 360 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  8 \[Pi]^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 720 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  488 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  1512 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  1008 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  480 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] + 192 \[Pi]^3 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] -  288 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  288 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  288 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 272 \[Pi]^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  576 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  688 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  432 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  288 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  128 \[Pi] Sin[5 \[Pi] t] + 64 \[Pi]^3 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] -  160 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  160 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 72 \[Pi] Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  72 \[Pi]^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] + 144 \[Pi] t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  216 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  216 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  144 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] - 48 \[Pi] Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  16 \[Pi]^3 Sin[7 \[Pi] t] - 48 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  48 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[7 \[Pi] t])))}, {-((2 Cos[(\[Pi] t)/ 2] (12 \[Pi] Cos[(\[Pi] t)/2] + \[Pi] (-5 + 6 t) Cos[( 3 \[Pi] t)/2] + 7 \[Pi] Cos[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] -  6 \[Pi] t Cos[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] + 2 \[Pi] Cos[(7 \[Pi] t)/2] +  8 Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] + 16 \[Pi]^2 Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] -  32 \[Pi]^2 t Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] +  16 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Sin[(\[Pi] t)/2] + 4 Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] -  4 \[Pi]^2 Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] +  8 \[Pi]^2 t Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] -  4 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Sin[(3 \[Pi] t)/2] - 4 Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] +  4 \[Pi]^2 Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] -  8 \[Pi]^2 t Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] +  4 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2]))/(\[Sqrt](240 +  591 \[Pi]^2 + 80 \[Pi]^4 - 492 \[Pi]^2 t - 320 \[Pi]^4 t +  492 \[Pi]^2 t^2 + 560 \[Pi]^4 t^2 - 480 \[Pi]^4 t^3 +  240 \[Pi]^4 t^4 + 126 \[Pi]^2 (-1 + 2 t) Cos[\[Pi] t] -  1/2 (720 + \[Pi]^2 (-325 - 972 t + 972 t^2) +  48 \[Pi]^4 (1 - 4 t + 7 t^2 - 6 t^3 + 3 t^4)) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + 120 \[Pi]^2 Cos[3 \[Pi] t] -  240 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[3 \[Pi] t] + 144 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  195 \[Pi]^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 48 \[Pi]^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  108 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  192 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  108 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  336 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  288 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  144 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  12 \[Pi]^2 Cos[5 \[Pi] t] + 24 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[5 \[Pi] t] -  24 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 139/2 \[Pi]^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  8 \[Pi]^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] - 102 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  32 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  102 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  56 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  48 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  24 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 18 \[Pi]^2 Cos[7 \[Pi] t] -  36 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[7 \[Pi] t] + 6 \[Pi]^2 Cos[8 \[Pi] t] +  568 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] + 264 \[Pi]^3 Sin[\[Pi] t] -  536 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[\[Pi] t] + 536 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[\[Pi] t] -  180 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 4 \[Pi]^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  360 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 244 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  756 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  504 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - 240 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  96 \[Pi]^3 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] - 144 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  144 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] + 144 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  136 \[Pi]^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] - 288 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  344 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  216 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  144 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 64 \[Pi] Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  32 \[Pi]^3 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 80 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  80 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 36 \[Pi] Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  36 \[Pi]^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] + 72 \[Pi] t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  108 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  108 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  72 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] - 24 \[Pi] Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  8 \[Pi]^3 Sin[7 \[Pi] t] - 24 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  24 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[7 \[Pi] t]))), (2 Sin[\[Pi] t] (-4 +  8 \[Pi]^2 t -  8 \[Pi]^2 t^2 + (4 - 4 \[Pi]^2 (-1 + t) t) Cos[2 \[Pi] t] -  3 \[Pi] (-1 + 2 t) Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  2 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t]))/(\[Sqrt](240 + 591 \[Pi]^2 +  80 \[Pi]^4 - 492 \[Pi]^2 t - 320 \[Pi]^4 t +  492 \[Pi]^2 t^2 + 560 \[Pi]^4 t^2 - 480 \[Pi]^4 t^3 +  240 \[Pi]^4 t^4 + 126 \[Pi]^2 (-1 + 2 t) Cos[\[Pi] t] -  1/2 (720 + \[Pi]^2 (-325 - 972 t + 972 t^2) +  48 \[Pi]^4 (1 - 4 t + 7 t^2 - 6 t^3 + 3 t^4)) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + 120 \[Pi]^2 Cos[3 \[Pi] t] -  240 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[3 \[Pi] t] + 144 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  195 \[Pi]^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 48 \[Pi]^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  108 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] + 192 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  108 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  336 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  288 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  144 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 12 \[Pi]^2 Cos[5 \[Pi] t] +  24 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[5 \[Pi] t] - 24 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  139/2 \[Pi]^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] - 8 \[Pi]^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  102 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 32 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  102 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  56 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  48 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  24 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 18 \[Pi]^2 Cos[7 \[Pi] t] -  36 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[7 \[Pi] t] + 6 \[Pi]^2 Cos[8 \[Pi] t] +  568 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] + 264 \[Pi]^3 Sin[\[Pi] t] -  536 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[\[Pi] t] + 536 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[\[Pi] t] -  180 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 4 \[Pi]^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  360 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 244 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  756 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  504 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  ...+  6 \[Pi] t Sin[(5 \[Pi] t)/2] -  2 \[Pi] Sin[(7 \[Pi] t)/2]))/(\[Sqrt](240 + 591 \[Pi]^2 +  80 \[Pi]^4 - 492 \[Pi]^2 t - 320 \[Pi]^4 t +  492 \[Pi]^2 t^2 + 560 \[Pi]^4 t^2 - 480 \[Pi]^4 t^3 +  240 \[Pi]^4 t^4 + 126 \[Pi]^2 (-1 + 2 t) Cos[\[Pi] t] -  1/2 (720 + \[Pi]^2 (-325 - 972 t + 972 t^2) +  48 \[Pi]^4 (1 - 4 t + 7 t^2 - 6 t^3 + 3 t^4)) Cos[ 2 \[Pi] t] + 120 \[Pi]^2 Cos[3 \[Pi] t] -  240 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[3 \[Pi] t] + 144 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  195 \[Pi]^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] - 48 \[Pi]^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  108 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  192 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  108 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  336 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] +  288 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  144 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[4 \[Pi] t] -  12 \[Pi]^2 Cos[5 \[Pi] t] + 24 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[5 \[Pi] t] -  24 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 139/2 \[Pi]^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  8 \[Pi]^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] - 102 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  32 \[Pi]^4 t Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  102 \[Pi]^2 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  56 \[Pi]^4 t^2 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] +  48 \[Pi]^4 t^3 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] -  24 \[Pi]^4 t^4 Cos[6 \[Pi] t] + 18 \[Pi]^2 Cos[7 \[Pi] t] -  36 \[Pi]^2 t Cos[7 \[Pi] t] + 6 \[Pi]^2 Cos[8 \[Pi] t] +  568 \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] t] + 264 \[Pi]^3 Sin[\[Pi] t] -  536 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[\[Pi] t] + 536 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[\[Pi] t] -  180 \[Pi] Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 4 \[Pi]^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  360 \[Pi] t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] + 244 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[2 \[Pi] t] -  756 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] +  504 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - 240 \[Pi] Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  96 \[Pi]^3 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] - 144 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[3 \[Pi] t] +  144 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[3 \[Pi] t] + 144 \[Pi] Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  136 \[Pi]^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] - 288 \[Pi] t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  344 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[4 \[Pi] t] +  216 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] -  144 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 64 \[Pi] Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  32 \[Pi]^3 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 80 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[5 \[Pi] t] +  80 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[5 \[Pi] t] - 36 \[Pi] Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  36 \[Pi]^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] + 72 \[Pi] t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  108 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[6 \[Pi] t] +  108 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] -  72 \[Pi]^3 t^3 Sin[6 \[Pi] t] - 24 \[Pi] Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  8 \[Pi]^3 Sin[7 \[Pi] t] - 24 \[Pi]^3 t Sin[7 \[Pi] t] +  24 \[Pi]^3 t^2 Sin[7 \[Pi] t])))}}}`

is such huge (The one is shortened (see `...`) to be presented here.) .

Addition. You ask "help me to get it's curvature curve in any kind of way and it's plot?" Here it is.

```
fs = FrenetSerretSystem[r[t], t];
fs[[1]][[1]] (*Curvature*)
```

> A very long expression

```
Plot[fs[[1]][[1]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: What is wrong in my answer? It is not a good practice to down vote without any explanation.

Comment: I am not the down vote. But I think it is recommend to only post `Simplify[FrenetSerretSystem[r[t], t]] // LeafCount` instead of the long result.

Comment: thanks. i will try to use it.